# Writing SubQuery in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I wrote a query in HQL, however, it gave me an error. While investigating the error, I realized that Hibernate does not allow a subquery inside FROM.

I am new to writing queries and hence don't know how to convert the below mentioned query into a format that will be accepted by Hibernate.

```
@Query("FROM (SELECT t, " + 
       "MAX(t.transactionId.versionId) OVER (PARTITION BY t.transactionId.referenceId) AS MAX_VER_ID " + 
       "FROM CurrentTransaction t) ABC " + 
       "where t.transactionId.versionId=MAX_VER_ID")
```

I do realize that SO is not a place for such questions, but it would be great if someone can help me in converting the above query for Hibernate.

EDIT : The error is,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileWatcher': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.service.FileWatcherService com.cprt.rtlistener.controller.FileWatcher.fileWatcher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileWatcherService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService com.cprt.rtlistener.service.FileWatcherService.currentTransactionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService.currentTransactionsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.service.FileWatcherService com.cprt.rtlistener.controller.FileWatcher.fileWatcher; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileWatcherService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService com.cprt.rtlistener.service.FileWatcherService.currentTransactionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService.currentTransactionsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileWatcherService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService com.cprt.rtlistener.service.FileWatcherService.currentTransactionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService.currentTransactionsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService com.cprt.rtlistener.service.FileWatcherService.currentTransactionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService.currentTransactionsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService.currentTransactionsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository com.cprt.rtlistener.service.crud.CurrentTransactionService.currentTransactionsRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'currentTransactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cprt.rtlistener.repository.CurrentTransactionRepository.searchAsIWish()!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:347)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 6 [FROM (SELECT t,MAX(t.transactionId.versionId) OVER (PARTITION BY t.transactionId.referenceId) AS MAX_VER_ID FROM com.cprt.rtlistener.entity.CurrentTransaction t) ABC    where t.transactionId.versionId=MAX_VER_ID]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 6 [FROM (SELECT t,MAX(t.transactionId.versionId) OVER (PARTITION BY t.transactionId.referenceId) AS MAX_VER_ID FROM com.cprt.rtlistener.entity.CurrentTransaction t) ABC    where t.transactionId.versionId=MAX_VER_ID]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 81 more
```

I tried this query, but it is also returning an error,

```
@Query("select t from CurrentTransaction t JOIN (SELECT t.transactionId.referenceId ,MAX(t.transactionId.versionId) AS MAX_VER FROM CurrentTransaction GROUP BY t.transactionId.referenceId ) MAX_VER ON t.t.transactionId.referenceId=MAX_VER.t.transactionId.referenceId AND t.t.transactionId.versionId=MAX_VER.MAX_VER")
```

Comment: Please include the error your get.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : I have added the error.

Comment: You can't. HQL doesn't support subqueries in from clause, nor max over partition by. Stick yo SQL for that query.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to translate the logic implemented with window functions to HQL / JPQL. Neither are these kinds of derived tables possible in HQL.

Stick with SQL and possibly use a native query to materialise the resulting entity:

```
List<CurrentTransaction> trx = em.createNativeQuery(
   "SELECT t.* "
 + "FROM ("
 + "  SELECT "
 + "    t,*, "
 + "    MAX(t.transactionId.versionId) "
 + "      OVER (PARTITION BY t.transactionId.referenceId) AS MAX_VER_ID " 
 + "  FROM CurrentTransaction t"
 + ") t " 
 + "WHERE t.transactionId.versionId = MAX_VER_ID"
 , CurrentTransaction.class)
 .getResultList();
```

Note, while the syntax that you're using to dereference nested records such as `t.transactionId.versionId` or `t.transactionId.referenceId` exists in some ORDBMS, I suspect that you've been trying to express relationship paths in HQL. You'll have to resort to classic SQL using JOIN in that case.